# WIFI Receive Data in Sleep Mode?

Tags: wi-fi, sleep

How can wifi receive data when it is in sleep mode? Will it wake up regularly, or do something else?
I tried to make a ping test to a full power management (sleep just after transmission) phone, and it wouldn't miss any packets. So I'm curious about the receipt progress.

Answer (score 0):

It does not turn off by default, but you can change that option in Settings>WiFi>Advanced